# MDX Using Query member for the filter value

Tags: filter, mdx

Hello I am trying to put a query member as an filter condition and the code I am trying to do is :

```
Member [ThisMonth] as VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now(),"yyyyMM")

  SET [currentdays] AS filter([D Date].[DAY ID].Members,
 [D Date].[MONTH ID]=[ThisMonth])
```

But The query did not recognize the Condition

```
Member [ThisMonth] as VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now(),"yyyyMM")

      SET [currentdays] AS filter([D Date].[DAY ID].Members,
     [D Date].[MONTH ID].&[201309])
```

The query therefore then return the desire result. I am just wondering is there anymore dynamic way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now(),"yyyyMM")` returns a string, not a member identifier. This is like in SQL `select 'myColumn' from myTable` which returns the literal string ´myColumn´ and not the contents of column `mycolumn`.

If you want to use the `Format` function, then you firstly need to construct the full unique name of the member, and secondly convert the string to a member identifier using `StrToMember`:

```
Member [ThisMonth] as '[D Date].[MONTH ID].&['
                      + VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now(),"yyyyMM")
                      + ']'    -- this returns a string!

   SET [currentdays] AS filter([D Date].[DAY ID].Members,
       StrToMember([ThisMonth]))
```

By the way: You do not need `Filter` here, and it can slow down queries dramatically, you can just use

```
SET [currentdays] AS { StrToMember([ThisMonth]) }
```